# Using the facebook api, how do I obtain the post id of a post created by sharing content from my website?

Tags: facebook, web, facebook-graph-api

After some research apparently until 2018 in the response body you would receive from the share dialog there would be a post-id if certain permissions were given. That seems to have since been removed however. Are there any ways of doing what I want now?

Comment: What would you need the post ID for?

Comment: Are you talking about the Share or Feed dialog? There is no way to get the post id from those, Facebook has removed this possibility because too many developers _abused_ it to reward users for sharing, which is absolutely not allowed.